# Add uniqueness: value may only occur once over four columns in 2 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 tables: users and members (these represent two types of users). Both tables include 2 columns: `email` and `new_email`. I would like validation within the model as well as migration files so that an email address can only exist once in these four column (so not once in each column, but all four columns taken together). How to implement this? So far I have:

1.Member Model (also included User model file):

```
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email,         presence: true,
                            length: { maximum: 255 },
                            format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                            uniqueness: { scope: :new_email, case_sensitive: false }
  validate :uniqueness_of_email_across_models
  validates :new_email,     presence: true,
                            length: { maximum: 255 },
                            format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                            uniqueness: { scope: :email, case_sensitive: false }
  validate :uniqueness_of_new_email_across_models

  private
    def uniqueness_of_email_across_models
      if User.where("lower(email) in (?)", [self.email.downcase, self.new_email.downcase]).first
        errors.add(:email, "There is already a user with this email address")
      end
    end

    def uniqueness_of_new_email_across_models
      if User.where("lower(new_email) in (?)", [self.email.downcase, self.new_email.downcase]).first
        errors.add(:new_email, "There is already a user with this email address")
      end
    end
```

**I think `scope: :new_email` is an incorrect implementation. I think this tests for uniqueness of the combination between the two columns, rather then uniqueness of the value in the two columns combined?** 
Would perhaps a customer validator be appropriate? That is, add to the private method the lines (checks in the member table, the same way as it checks in the user table):

```
  if self.where("lower(email) in (?)", [self.email.downcase, self.new_email.downcase]).first
    errors.add(:email, "There is already a user with this email address")
```

2.Member migration:

```
  t.string   :new_email
  t.datetime :activation_sent_at

  add_index :members, [:email, :new_email], unique: true
```

**Not sure how in the migration file to include uniqueness beyond one column, i.q., uniqueness over all four columns. Current implementation, I think only checks for a combination of email and new_email, and doesn't look at the other table at all.**

**Update:** I guess the bigger question is how to implement what I want to achieve. I'm now thinking it might be easier to not validate `new_email` for uniqueness. Instead when the user clicks the confirmation link and the app want to overwrite `email` with `new_email`, at that point validation of uniqueness is applied. Would that be a more appropriate implementation?

Comment: My rationale for `new_email`: If a user/member wants to change its email address, the new address is initially stored there. When confirmed it overwrites `email`. Does this make sense or this normally done a different way? The idea is: what if a user/member misspells his new email address. If it would immediately overwrite `email` then that user will no longer have access to its account. How is this "normally" implemented?

Comment: So you meant adding `scope: [:new_email, :email]` to the model file? Wouldn't this validate only uniqueness for a unique combination of the values in these two columns? Rather then a unique value irrespective whether that value is in the column for `email` or `new_email`? In addition, any idea what I should do in the migration file?

Comment: I think you're right in that's now how `scope` works. You can consolidate your queries to check the emails like this `.where("lower(email) in (?)", [self.email.downcase, self.new_email.downcase])` That will help make things a bit faster. Depending on your database engine you may not be able to enforce uniqueness over 2 columns. What are you using?

Comment: Thanks I refactored my original post as suggested. I'm using PostgreSQL. If I compare for example with Twitter, my rationale is similar: you provide a new email address but the old email address remains the email address in use as long as the new email address has not been confirmed.

Comment: You may be able to add a `CHECK` constraint, something like this `CHECK (email NOT IN new_email)` http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp I'm not sure if this will work, I can't find any examples of using the `in` operator in a `check` I also don't know how you would add this through a migration.

Comment: Why not implement a two part overwrite, where new_email is stored an email is sent to the "new_email" and then add a confirmation link to allow the user to confirm this is a true email address for them before overwriting email with new_email. This seems like it would handle your typing mistakes issue.

Comment: After some testing, `CHECK (email NOT IN new_email)` will test against only the values being inserted. It seems for this to work you would need to define an sql function that returns current unique values of that column to compare against.

Comment: Thanks, I think what @engineersmnky says makes sense and prevents me from doing any "hardcoding of SQL" (I'm a bit too new to all of this to do that). It's also what I meant in the update I added to the original post. And the validation at the model level can still take place as planned. I do wonder in that area though: Is anyone certain if `scope: [:new_email, :email]` tests for unique combinations of the two, or whether it tests that a certain value is only allowed to occur once in these columns combined?

Comment: you are correct it will validate if it is unique using a combination of those 2 fields which is not what you want. To validate this uniqueness yo uwill have to run a query and check for existence against that e.g. `def unique_email; emails = (Members.pluck(:email,:new_email) + User.pluck(:email,:new_email)).flatten.uniq; errors.add(:new_email,"must be unique") if emails.include?(self.new_email); end` and use `validate :unique_email`

Comment: Ok, thanks, this gives me a good idea of the direction to move into.